# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined in SELECT *

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00918

Getting ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined: running this SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT(coaches.id),
    people.*,
    users.*,
    coaches.*
  FROM "COACHES"
  INNER JOIN people ON people.id = coaches.person_id
  INNER JOIN users ON coaches.person_id = users.person_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN organizations_users ON organizations_users.user_id = users.id
) WHERE rownum <= 25
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Don't think this is your problem, but [`DISTINCT`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#sthref9766) isn't a function; should be `DISTINCT coaches.id, ...`.

Comment: The DISTINCT in this example will work just fine, but is quite confusing.  The distinct will still be on the whole row.  The parenthesis go with the column name and effectively do nothing.  This is the same as writing "select distinct people.*, (coaches.id), ...".  It is bad practice to have the parenthesis though, since it does make it confusing to look at.

Comment: @APC - not sure if that was aimed at me or the OP; I suspect me. I do know distinct is across all columns, but my comment was rushed and unhelpful - seems my reading was rushed too as I was (as @Craig feared) confused by the parentheses. You're both right, obviously *8-)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

A query's projection can only have one instance of a given name.  As your WHERE clause shows, you have several tables with a column called ID.  Because you are selecting `*` your projection will have several columns called ID.  Or it would have were it not for the compiler hurling ORA-00918.

The solution is quite simple: you will have to expand the projection to explicitly select named columns.  Then you can either leave out the duplicate columns, retaining just (say) COACHES.ID or use column aliases: `coaches.id as COACHES_ID`.

Perhaps that strikes you as a lot of typing, but it is the only way.  If it is any comfort, `SELECT *` is regarded as bad practice in production code: explicitly named columns are much safer.

Comment: Anytime you use select * when you have a join, you have duplicated columns of data and that wastes resources.

Answer (score 12):

You have multiple columns named the same thing in your inner query, so the error is raised in the outer query.  If you get rid of the outer query, it should run, although still be confusing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    coaches.id,
    people.*,
    users.*,
    coaches.*
FROM "COACHES"
    INNER JOIN people ON people.id = coaches.person_id
    INNER JOIN users ON coaches.person_id = users.person_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN organizations_users ON organizations_users.user_id = users.id
WHERE
    rownum <= 25
```

It would be **much** better (for readability and performance both) to specify exactly what fields you need from each of the tables instead of selecting them all anyways.  Then if you really need two fields called the same thing from different tables, use column aliases to differentiate between them.

Comment: +1 This solves the problem because the outer SELECT is unnecessary as the code stands.  If  the outer query was required - say because the inner query had had an ORDER BY - then it would be a different matter.

Comment: The code is generated by an ORM library so we have no control over the outer SELECT generation. Just removing outer select helps but unfortunately it is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

You can also see this error when selecting for a union where corresponding columns can be null.

```
select * from (select D.dept_no, D.nullable_comment
                  from dept D
       union
               select R.dept_no, NULL
                 from redundant_dept R
)
```

This apparently confuses the parser, a solution is to assign a column alias to the always null column.

```
select * from (select D.dept_no, D.comment
                  from dept D
       union
               select R.dept_no, NULL "nullable_comment"
                 from redundant_dept R
)
```

The alias does not have to be the same as the corresponding column, but the column heading in the result is driven by the first query from among the union members, so it's probably a good practice.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  
        per_all_people_f.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER 
        , MAX(per_all_people_f.LAST_UPDATE_DATE) 
        , per_all_people_f.KNOWN_AS  FULL_NAME
        , to_char(notified_termination_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS termination_date 
        , :FROM_DATE  DATE1
        , :TO_DATE DATE2
--      , D_LEAVING_REASON AS D_LEAVING_REASON
        , CASE substr(substr(hr_all_organization_units_tl.NAME, instr(hr_all_organization_units_tl.NAME, '.') + 1), 1, 1)
        WHEN 'B'  THEN
            'إدارة الاتصالات وتقنية المعلومات'
        WHEN 'C'  THEN
            'إدارة المشاريع'
        WHEN 'D'  THEN
            'الإدارة القانونية'
        WHEN 'E'  THEN
            'إدارة الصحه والسلامة والبيئه'
        WHEN 'F'  THEN
            'إدارة هندسة المكامن والانتاج'
        WHEN 'G'  THEN
            'إدارة الهندسة'
        WHEN 'H'  THEN
            'إدارة العمليات'
        WHEN 'J'  THEN
            'إدارة الحفر وصيانة الآبار'
        WHEN 'K'  THEN
            'إدارة المواد'
        WHEN 'L'  THEN
            'إدارة النقل والخدمات'
        WHEN 'M'  THEN
            'إدارة الاستكشاف'
        WHEN 'N'  THEN
            'إدارة فرع بنغازي'
        WHEN 'P'  THEN
            'إدارة التخطيط'
        WHEN 'R'  THEN
            'إدارة المالية'
        WHEN 'T'  THEN
            'إدارة المراجعه'
        WHEN 'W'  THEN
            'إدارة التدريب والتطوير'
        WHEN 'Y'  THEN
            'إدارة شؤون الموظفين'
            else case  substr(substr(hr_all_organization_units_tl.NAME, instr(hr_all_organization_units_tl.NAME, '.') + 1), 1, 3)
              WHEN 'A11'  THEN
            'لجنة المناقصات'
        WHEN 'A10'  THEN
            'لجنة الادارة'
        WHEN 'A12'  THEN
            'قسم الاعلام '
            end
        END  DEPARTMENT
    , CASE d_leaving_reason 
        WHEN 'Retirement'  THEN
            'التقاعد'
        END 
        LEAVING_REASON1 
FROM    per_all_people_f
LEFT JOIN per_periods_of_service_v ON per_all_people_f.person_id = per_periods_of_service_v.person_id
LEFT JOIN per_assignments_f ON per_all_people_f.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = per_assignments_f.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN hr_all_organization_units_tl ON per_assignments_f.ORGANIZATION_ID = hr_all_organization_units_tl.ORGANIZATION_ID
WHERE   notified_termination_date >= TO_DATE(:FROM_DATE,'MM-YYYY') AND notified_termination_date <= TO_DATE(:TO_DATE,'MM-YYYY')
--      AND D_LEAVING_REASON = 'Retirement'
        AND CURRENT_EMPLOYEE_FLAG IS NULL AND employee_number IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,d_leaving_reason,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,KNOWN_AS,notified_termination_date
,:FROM_DATE,:TO_DATE,NAME
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How your answer is related to the question?