# Column ambiguously defined in subquery using rownums

Tags: sql, pagination, subquery, ambiguous, ora-00918

I have to execute a SQL made from some users and show its results. An example SQL could be this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, where table1.id = table2.id
```

This SQL works fine as it is, but I need to manually add pagination and show the rownum, so the SQL ends up like this.

```
SELECT z.* 
FROM(       
    SELECT y.*, ROWNUM rn
    FROM (                   
        SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, where table1.id = table2.id
    ) y      
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 50) z         
WHERE rn > 0
```

This throws an exception: "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined" because both Table1 and Table2 contains a field with the same name ("id").

What could be the best way to avoid this?

Regards.

- UPDATE

In the end, we had to go for the ugly way and parse each SQL coming before executing them. Basically, we resolved asterisks to discover what fields we needed to add, and alias every field with an unique id. This introduced a performance penalty but our client understood it was the only option given the requirements.

I will mark Lex answer as it´s the solution we ended up working on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined in SELECT \*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233086/ora-00918-column-ambiguously-defined-in-select)

Comment: @Ben Not exactly, unfortunately, since the special requirements I had made those answers non desirable back then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to specify aliasses for (at least one of) table1.id and table2.id. And possibly for any other corresponding columnnames as well.

So instead of `SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1, table2` use something like:

```
SELECT t1.id t1id, t2.id t2id [rest of columns] FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
```

I'm not familiar with Oracle syntax, but I think you'll get the idea.

Comment: Thanks Lex, that would fix it but it´s not applicable in my case. Since I just receive the SQL as is, I would have to parse it, but getting the fields of a * query and aliasing each one would be too much. And I can´t tell the users to fix the SQL since it works fine for them.

Comment: In that case, maybe you can avoid using y.* and specify column names you need from t1 and t2. Maybe if you don't specify the id column of either it'll work? (provided that you don't need the id columns)

Comment: I need to show all columns since it´s up to the user to choose the fields included.

Comment: That makes it a lot harder. I can't think of a way to do this... Sorry

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for an answer to something similar. I was referencing an aliased sub-query that had a couple of NULL columns. I had to alias the NULL columns because I had more than one;

select a.*, t2.column, t2.column, t2.column
(select t1.column, t1.column, NULL, NULL, t1.column from t1
where t1='VALUE') a
left outer join t2 on t2.column=t1.column;

Once i aliased the NULL columns in the sub-query it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you could modify the query syntactically (or get the users to do so) to use explicit `JOIN` syntax with the **`USING`** clause, this would automatically fix the problem at hand:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 USING (id)
```

The `USING` clause does the same as `ON t1.id = t2.id` (or the implicit `JOIN` you have in the question), except that only one `id` column remains in the result, thereby eliminating your problem.

You would still run into problems if there are more columns with identical names that are not included in the `USING` clause. Aliases as described by @Lex are indispensable then.

Comment: True, the problem is that we need retrocompatibility with all existing SQL´s, and the company has already stated that they won´t change them since they worked before.

This problem was introduced because we are migrating from a desktop client to a full web app, and it needed pagination because our components are more heavyweight in comparison to the old, plain grid control used previously.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace null values function to fix this.

```sql
SELECT z.* 
FROM(       
    SELECT y.*, ROWNUM rn
    FROM (                   
        SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, where 

        NVL(table1.id,0) = NVL(table2.id,0)

    ) y      
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 50) z         
WHERE rn > 0
```

Comment: Thanks @openritwanz, but there where no null id columns. The error happened because of colums retrieved with duplicated names. This does not fix this.