# sql select query - alias name for column in joins is not working

Tags: sql

I have a query which is working fine..

```
SELECT 
    WSDEFN.WORKSPACE_DISPLAY_NM,
    LAYDEFN.LAYOUT_DISPLAY_NM,
    WSLMAP.POSITION,
    LAYDEFN.LAYOUT,
    LAYDEFN.PROPORTION,
    LAYDEFN.LAYOUT_ID,
    WSDEFN.WORKSPACE_ID,
    LAYDEFN.BUNDLE_KEY 
FROM 
    WORKSPACE_DEFINITION WSDEFN,
    WORKSPACE_LAYOUT_MAP WSLMAP,
    LAYOUT_DEFINITION LAYDEFN
WHERE 
    WORKSPACE_ID = WSLMAP.WORKSPACE_ID
    AND WSLMAP.LAYOUT_ID = LAYDEFN.LAYOUT_ID 
    AND WSDEFN.OD_USER_NO = '-1' 
    AND WSDEFN.OD_GCIF = '-1'
ORDER BY 
    wsdefn.workspace_id, WSLMAP.POSITION
```

But I want to fetch the `WSDEFN.WORKSPACE_ID` as `WORKSPACE_ID`.

I tried this

```
WSDEFN.WORKSPACE_ID AS WORKSPACE_ID,
```

but I get an error

> 'column ambiguously defined'

Could you give me a solution?

Comment: I don't follow, why do you want to give it an alias which is the same as its name? Also, you should define your `joins` explicitly using `join....on..` syntax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233086/ora-00918-column-ambiguously-defined-in-select

Comment: the following will be added to the query by local framework UPPER(TRIM(WORKSPACE_ID)) LIKE '%' || UPPER(TRIM(?)) || '%' .
i need it for that purpose.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: hi marc_s,  you are right. I 'm comfort new sql style only. But I am working with an enhancement application.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be missing the table alias in the where clause.

Did you try this?

```
            SELECT 
                WSDEFN.WORKSPACE_DISPLAY_NM,
                LAYDEFN.LAYOUT_DISPLAY_NM,
                WSLMAP.POSITION,
                LAYDEFN.LAYOUT,
                LAYDEFN.PROPORTION,
                LAYDEFN.LAYOUT_ID,
                WSDEFN.WORKSPACE_ID AS WORKSPACE_ID,  
                LAYDEFN.BUNDLE_KEY 
            FROM 
                WORKSPACE_DEFINITION WSDEFN,
                WORKSPACE_LAYOUT_MAP WSLMAP,
                LAYOUT_DEFINITION LAYDEFN
           WHERE 
               WSDEFN.WORKSPACE_ID = WSLMAP.WORKSPACE_ID
           AND 
                WSLMAP.LAYOUT_ID      = LAYDEFN.LAYOUT_ID 
           AND 
                WSDEFN.OD_USER_NO='-1' AND WSDEFN.OD_GCIF='-1'
           ORDER BY 
                wsdefn.workspace_id,WSLMAP.POSITION
```

Comment: thanks working fine... :-)    may know the reason. i did the same but not worked. may know why?

Comment: It's already written in my answer, the field `WORKSPACE_ID` in the `WHERE` clause exist probably with the same name in some other table involved in the `JOIN`; so you have to specify which of them you are referring in order to don't have ambiguity.