# DRF: related field name throwing error column ambiguously defined

Tags: django, oracle, django-rest-framework

I have models like

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
         managed = False 

class ResourceMgmt(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='cpe_mgmt_profile')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

Serializer like

```
class ResourceMgmtSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='profile.name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ResourceMgmt
        fields = (<tuple of fields including profile_name>)
```

View like

```
class RunningSchedules(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = ResourceMgmtSerializer
    model = ResourceMgmt
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter, filters.SearchFilter,)
    ordering_fields = (<tuple of fields including profile_name as profile__name>)
    ordering = ('-schedule_start_time',)
    search_fields = ordering_fields
```

Now when I hit url like `?ordering=profile__name` I get an error `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`.  I know what this is error is, but can't seem to figure out why is it happening with Django ORM

**Update :**

> It was a bug that has been [fixed](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24367) in Django==1.8, but I found it
>   in Django==1.10.

Comment: did you migrated some changes before and then made some changes?

Comment: I will have to see, if another collaborator had done that. But again django is not managing models.

Comment: to me it happened as I added a field `id` in my model. You might consider removing it.

Comment: I shall try it.

Comment: may I know why do you have managed = False on your Meta?

Comment: @JohnbabuKoppolu because django is not managing tables.

Comment: @KishorPawar - I understand. but then don't you need db_table in Meta?

Comment: clearly there is a join happening and there are multiple id columns which are not namespaced - refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233086/ora-00918-column-ambiguously-defined-in-select - may be enabling db query log might help you in getting to the real issue here

Comment: Oh... It's there. I added only that portion into question to let you all know that django is not managing tables.

Comment: @JohnbabuKoppolu I shall try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... When I reopen the [ticket here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24367#comment:4) Django developer(Simon Charette) given a pointer and it turned out that my overridden `get_queryset` was a culprit.

an erroneous query is

```
ResourceMgmt.objects.filter(is_active='Y')\
    .filter(schedule_next_run_time__lt=future)\ # future is calculated date
    .filter(schedule_end_time__gt=now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))\
    .extra(where=["schedule_next_run_time > sysdate - (schedule_frequency/1440)",
                 "owner_id IN ( \
                  select id from cpe_user \
                  where is_active='Y' \
                  connect by prior id = parent_id start with id = % s)"], 154)
```

Fixed query is

```
ResourceMgmt.objects.filter(is_active='Y')\
    .filter(schedule_next_run_time__lt=future)\ # future is calculated date
    .filter(schedule_end_time__gt=now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))\
    .extra(where=["schedule_next_run_time > sysdate - (schedule_frequency/1440)",
                 "cpe_resource_mgmt.owner_id IN ( \ ### look at this line.
                  select id from cpe_user \
                  where is_active='Y' \
                  connect by prior id = parent_id start with id = % s)"], 154)
```

**So as Oracle error said, `column ambiguously defined`, it actually meant `owner_id` in `extra` clause.**