# How to solve "column ambiguously defined" for the following code

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

I am trying to merge two tables. But there are a lots of aggregation, condition inside each table.
The error message show up at Line 3.  I already erased a major part of the case statement since they shouldn't be the issues.

```
SELECT "Org_ID", "Vendor_Name", "Vendor_Number", "PO_Project", "PO_Number", "PO_Distribution_ID" -- Not sure about PO date, differnt lines under same PO has different Line_create_date
    , "Invoice_Date", "First_Due_Date", "Invoice_ID", "Company_Code", Adj2020_Estimated_Payment_Date 
    , Inv_Line_Amt_USD_Dist, "Payment_Date", Paid_Amt_Dist_PO_USD, "Unpaid_USD_Abs", First_layer, Second_layer, Third_layer
FROM
    (SELECT  t2."Org_ID", t2."Vendor_Name", t2."Vendor_Number", t2."PO_Project", t2."PO_Number", t2."PO_Distribution_ID" -- Not sure about PO date, differnt lines under same PO has different Line_create_date
    , t2."Invoice_Date", t2."First_Due_Date", t3."Invoice_ID", t3."Company_Code", t2.Line_Amt_USD, t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD, t2.Adj2020_Estimated_Payment_Date
    , ROUND((t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD - t2.Inv_Paid_Amt_USD), 2) AS Unpaid_USD
    , ROUND(t2.Line_Amt_USD/COUNT(t2."PO_Distribution_ID") OVER (PARTITION BY t2."PO_Distribution_ID", t2."Invoice_ID"), 2) AS Inv_Line_Amt_USD_Dist
    , t3."Payment_Date", ROUND(t3."Paid_Amt_USD"*(t2.Line_Amt_USD/t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD), 2) AS Paid_Amt_Dist_PO_USD, t3."Paid_Amt_USD" AS Total_Paid_Amt_USD
    , Case 
        WHEN ROUND((t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD - t2.Inv_Paid_Amt_USD), 2) < 0
            THEN 0
            ELSE ROUND((t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD - t2.Inv_Paid_Amt_USD), 2)
    END AS "Unpaid_USD_Abs"
    ,Case
        WHEN 
        TEHN
        ELSE
    END AS First_layer
    , Case 
        WHEN 
        TEHN
        ELSE
    END AS Second_layer
    , Case 
        WHEN 
        TEHN
        ELSE
    END AS Third_layer
FROM
(
    SELECT t1."Org_ID", t1."PO_Project", t1."PO_Number", t1."PO_Distribution_ID", t1."Invoice_ID", t1."Vendor_Name", t1."Vendor_Number", t1."Invoice_Date" 
    , t1."First_Due_Date", ROUND(SUM(t1."Line_Amt_USD"),2) AS Line_Amt_USD, ROUND(AVG(t1."Inv_Total_Amt"/NVL(t1."Conv_Rate_USD", 1)), 2) AS Inv_Total_Amt_USD,
    ROUND(AVG(t1."Inv_Paid_Amt"/ NVL(t1."Conv_Rate_USD", 1)),2) AS Inv_Paid_Amt_USD
    ,CASE
        WHEN '01-JAN-20' <  TO_DATE(("First_Due_Date"), 'DD-MON-YY') AND  TO_DATE(("First_Due_Date"), 'DD-MON-YY') < '01-JAN-24'
        THEN '01-JAN-24'
        ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(("First_Due_Date"), 'DD-MON-YY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
    END AS Adj2020_Estimated_Payment_Date
    FROM "RPT_VIEW"."RPT_AP_INVOICE_DIST" t1
    WHERE t1."PO_Number" IS NOT NULL 
    AND t1."Line_Amt_USD" <> 0 
    AND t1."Line_Amt_USD" IS NOT NULL 
    AND t1."Inv_Total_Amt" <> 0
    AND t1."Inv_Total_Amt" IS NOT NULL 
    AND t1."PO_Glbl_Acct" in ('12145', '12155')
    GROUP BY t1."PO_Distribution_ID", t1."Invoice_ID", t1."Org_ID", t1."PO_Project", t1."PO_Number", t1."Vendor_Name", t1."Vendor_Number", t1."Invoice_Date",t1."First_Due_Date"
) t2
LEFT JOIN "RPT_VIEW"."RPT_AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS" t3
ON t2."Invoice_ID" = t3."Invoice_ID"
WHERE extract(YEAR from t2."Invoice_Date") in (2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024)
AND t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD  <> 0
AND t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD  IS NOT NULL) t4 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    "Hdr_Closed_Code",
    "Shipment_Create_Date",
    "Operating_Unit",
    "Ship_To_Location",
    "Global_Account",
    "Promise_Date",
    "Supplier_Number",
    "Supplier_Name",
    "PO_Number",
    "Project_Number",
    "Ship_Approved_Flag",
    "Payment_Term_Days",
    "USD_Unbilled_Abs",
    ("Payment_Term_Days" + "Promise_Date") AS "Estimated_Payment_Date",
    "PO_Distribution_Id",
    CASE
        WHEN '01-JAN-20' <  TO_DATE(("Payment_Term_Days" + "Promise_Date"), 'DD-MON-YY') AND  TO_DATE(("Payment_Term_Days" + "Promise_Date"), 'DD-MON-YY') < '01-JAN-24'
        THEN '01-JAN-24'
        ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(("Payment_Term_Days" + "Promise_Date"), 'DD-MON-YY'), 'DD-MON-YY')
    END AS Adj2020_Estimated_Payment_Date
FROM
    (SELECT
        "Hdr_Closed_Code",
        "Ship_Canceled_Flag",
        "Shipment_Create_Date",
        "Operating_Unit",
        "Ship_To_Location",
        "Global_Account",
        "Payment_Term",
        "Promise_Date",
        "Supplier_Number",
        "Supplier_Name",
        "PO_Number",
        "Project_Number",
        "USD_Ordered_Amt",
        "USD_Billed_Amt",
        ROUND("Quantity_Canceled" * NVL("Conv_Rate", 1), 2) AS "USD_Quantity_Canceled",
        "USD_Ordered_Amt" - "USD_Billed_Amt" - ROUND("Quantity_Canceled" * NVL("Conv_Rate", 1), 2) AS "USD_Unbilled",
        "Ship_Approved_Flag",
        "Ship_Canceled_Flag",
        "PO_Distribution_Id",
        CASE
            WHEN ("USD_Ordered_Amt" - "USD_Billed_Amt" - ROUND("Quantity_Canceled" * NVL("Conv_Rate", 1), 2)) < 0
            THEN 0
            ELSE ("USD_Ordered_Amt" - "USD_Billed_Amt" - ROUND("Quantity_Canceled" * NVL("Conv_Rate", 1), 2))
        END AS "USD_Unbilled_Abs",
        CASE
            WHEN "Payment_Term" ='Pay in Zero Day'THEN 0
            WHEN "Payment_Term" ='Pay in One Day'THEN 1
            WHEN "Payment_Term" ='Pay in One Day from Receipt'THEN 1
            WHEN "Payment_Term" ='Pay in 10 days'THEN 10
            ELSE 0
        END AS "Payment_Term_Days"
    FROM "RPT_VIEW"."RPT_PO_INFO" 
    WHERE "Global_Account" IN ('12145', '12155'))) t5
ON t4."PO_Distribution_ID" = t5."PO_Distribution_Id"
```

Please give me some adivise on it. I really need help

Comment: Hi Paul, here is the full error message:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 71

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined in SELECT \*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233086/ora-00918-column-ambiguously-defined-in-select)

Comment: Line 3 position 71 is `Unpaid_USD_Abs`. Qualify it like this `t2.Unpaid_USD_Abs` or which ever is correct

Answer (score 1):

When you are selecting from multiple nested sub-queries, it is best to *ALWAYS* use table aliases in your `SELECT` statements, using the correct table alias will help you avoid this error.

Based on the error message:

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined 00918. 
00000 - "column ambiguously defined" 
*Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 3 Column: 71
```

The ambiguous column is likely to be `Adj2020_Estimated_Payment_Date`, although this is line 2 in the query you have pasted it does start at column 71.

Further to this we can see that 2 of your join queries, `t4` and `t5` both have a field named `Adj2020_Estimated_Payment_Date`, so you will need to choose which one of those fields to return in the main query or if you want both of them or if there is some sort of appropriate *coalesce* logic for this field that would be appropriate.

---

If you are not able to follow the *Line* and *Column* reference in the error message to identify the field reference that causes the error, then a simple troubleshooting technique is to comment out all the fields and uncomment them one-by-one and execute the query in between each attempt, then through trial and error you will find the field in question when the query first fails, the last field you added will be the culprit.

You should identify `PO_Number` and `PO_Distribution_ID` will both also cause the same error and will need to explicitly reference the fields you wish to use via the appropriate table alias.

---

As an additional note, if you use indents and additional line breaks to visually identify the nested subqueries within the `FROM` and `JOIN` statements you might find it easier to identify the duplicate fields or to uncomment sections of the query to assist you with debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If you are struggling to work out where the "column ambiguously defined" error is coming from then:

1. Format your query neatly with, at most, one statement on each line and consistent indentation. This won't fix any problems but it will make debugging simpler.
2. Prefix **ALL** column identifiers with the identifier for the table/inline-view that it comes from.
3. Move nested sub-queries from the main query into sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clauses.
4. Divide-and-conquer and remove (or comment out) half the query and see if it works - if it doesn't then remove (or comment out) half of the remaining query and repeat. When it starts working then add in a bit that you removed and if that doesn't work then debug only that part (or remove half of the part you just added until you can find which specific part doesn't work).

Apart from that:

- Using quoted identifiers is considered bad practice. In future, you should consider creating tables that do not use quoted identifiers so that you do not have to quote them and use the correct case in all the queries.
- **NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on a column that is already a `DATE` data type as you will implicitly convert the column to a string and then back to a date which is, at best, pointless - at worst, your query will break if it is run by someone with different NLS settings to your defaults. If you intend to ignore the time component of a `DATE` then use `TRUNC` (and never use `TO_DATE`) - but if you don't need to ignore the time component then just compare the column directly.
- Similarly, **NEVER** compare a date to a string. `'01-JAN-20'` is not a `DATE`, it is a string literal and you are relying on an implicit cast to convert it to a `DATE` (which will cause your query to break if it is run in a session where someone has different NLS settings to your defaults). Either use a `DATE` literal such as `DATE '2020-01-01'` or use `TO_DATE('01-JAN-20', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')`.
- `extract(YEAR from t2."Invoice_Date") in (2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024)` will not use an index on the `"Invoice_Date"` column. You would need a separate function-based index on `extract(YEAR from t2."Invoice_Date")`. You may be better to use `DATE '2020-01-01' <= t2."Invoice_Date" AND t2."Invoice_Date" < DATE '2025-01-01'`.

Something like:

```sql
WITH t2 AS (
  SELECT t1."Org_ID",
         t1."PO_Project",
         t1."PO_Number",
         t1."PO_Distribution_ID",
         t1."Invoice_ID",
         t1."Vendor_Name",
         t1."Vendor_Number",
         t1."Invoice_Date",
         t1."First_Due_Date",
         ROUND(SUM(t1."Line_Amt_USD"),2) AS Line_Amt_USD,
         ROUND(AVG(t1."Inv_Total_Amt"/NVL(t1."Conv_Rate_USD", 1)), 2) AS Inv_Total_Amt_USD,
         ROUND(AVG(t1."Inv_Paid_Amt"/ NVL(t1."Conv_Rate_USD", 1)),2) AS Inv_Paid_Amt_USD,
         CASE
         WHEN DATE '2020-01-01' <  t1."First_Due_Date"
         AND  t1."First_Due_Date" < DATE '2024-01-01'
         THEN DATE '2023-01-01'
         ELSE t1."First_Due_Date"
         END AS Adj2020_Estimated_Payment_Date
  FROM   "RPT_VIEW"."RPT_AP_INVOICE_DIST" t1
  WHERE  t1."PO_Number" IS NOT NULL 
  AND    t1."Line_Amt_USD" <> 0 
  AND    t1."Line_Amt_USD" IS NOT NULL 
  AND    t1."Inv_Total_Amt" <> 0
  AND    t1."Inv_Total_Amt" IS NOT NULL 
  AND    t1."PO_Glbl_Acct" in ('12145', '12155')
  GROUP BY
         t1."PO_Distribution_ID",
         t1."Invoice_ID",
         t1."Org_ID",
         t1."PO_Project",
         t1."PO_Number",
         t1."Vendor_Name",
         t1."Vendor_Number",
         t1."Invoice_Date",
         t1."First_Due_Date"
),
t4 AS (
  SELECT t2."Org_ID",
         t2."Vendor_Name",
         t2."Vendor_Number",
         t2."PO_Project",
         t2."PO_Number",
         t2."PO_Distribution_ID", -- Not sure about PO date, differnt lines under same PO has different Line_create_date
         t2."Invoice_Date",
         t2."First_Due_Date",
         t3."Invoice_ID",
         t3."Company_Code",
         t2.Line_Amt_USD,
         t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD,
         t2.Adj2020_Estimated_Payment_Date,
         ROUND((t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD - t2.Inv_Paid_Amt_USD), 2)
           AS Unpaid_USD,
         ROUND(t2.Line_Amt_USD/COUNT(t2."PO_Distribution_ID") OVER (PARTITION BY t2."PO_Distribution_ID", t2."Invoice_ID"), 2)
           AS Inv_Line_Amt_USD_Dist,
         t3."Payment_Date",
         ROUND(t3."Paid_Amt_USD"*(t2.Line_Amt_USD/t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD), 2)
           AS Paid_Amt_Dist_PO_USD,
         t3."Paid_Amt_USD" AS Total_Paid_Amt_USD,
         GREATEST(ROUND((t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD - t2.Inv_Paid_Amt_USD), 2), 0)
           AS "Unpaid_USD_Abs"
         --, Case WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END AS First_layer
         --, Case WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END AS Second_layer
         --, Case WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END AS Third_layer
  FROM   t2
         LEFT JOIN "RPT_VIEW"."RPT_AP_INVOICE_PAYMENTS" t3
         ON t2."Invoice_ID" = t3."Invoice_ID"
  WHERE  DATE '2020-01-01' <= t2."Invoice_Date"
  AND    t2."Invoice_Date" < DATE '2025-01-01'
  AND    t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD  <> 0
  AND    t2.Inv_Total_Amt_USD  IS NOT NULL  
),
t5 AS (
  SELECT "Hdr_Closed_Code",
         "Shipment_Create_Date",
         "Operating_Unit",
         "Ship_To_Location",
         "Global_Account",
         "Promise_Date",
         "Supplier_Number",
         "Supplier_Name",
         "PO_Number",
         "Project_Number",
         "Ship_Approved_Flag",
         "Payment_Term_Days",
         "USD_Unbilled_Abs",
         ("Payment_Term_Days" + "Promise_Date") AS "Estimated_Payment_Date",
         "PO_Distribution_Id",
         CASE
         WHEN DATE '2020-01-01' <  "Payment_Term_Days" + "Promise_Date"
         AND  "Payment_Term_Days" + "Promise_Date" < DATE '2024-01-01'
         THEN DATE '2024-01-01'
         ELSE "Payment_Term_Days" + "Promise_Date"
         END AS Adj2020_Estimated_Payment_Date
  FROM   (
    SELECT  "Hdr_Closed_Code",
            "Ship_Canceled_Flag",
            "Shipment_Create_Date",
            "Operating_Unit",
            "Ship_To_Location",
            "Global_Account",
            "Payment_Term",
            "Promise_Date",
            "Supplier_Number",
            "Supplier_Name",
            "PO_Number",
            "Project_Number",
            "USD_Ordered_Amt",
            "USD_Billed_Amt",
            ROUND("Quantity_Canceled" * NVL("Conv_Rate", 1), 2) AS "USD_Quantity_Canceled",
            "USD_Ordered_Amt" - "USD_Billed_Amt" - ROUND("Quantity_Canceled" * NVL("Conv_Rate", 1), 2) AS "USD_Unbilled",
            "Ship_Approved_Flag",
            "Ship_Canceled_Flag",
            "PO_Distribution_Id",
            CASE
            WHEN ("USD_Ordered_Amt" - "USD_Billed_Amt" - ROUND("Quantity_Canceled" * NVL("Conv_Rate", 1), 2)) < 0
            THEN 0
            ELSE ("USD_Ordered_Amt" - "USD_Billed_Amt" - ROUND("Quantity_Canceled" * NVL("Conv_Rate", 1), 2))
            END AS "USD_Unbilled_Abs",
            CASE
            WHEN "Payment_Term" ='Pay in Zero Day'THEN 0
            WHEN "Payment_Term" ='Pay in One Day'THEN 1
            WHEN "Payment_Term" ='Pay in One Day from Receipt'THEN 1
            WHEN "Payment_Term" ='Pay in 10 days'THEN 10
            ELSE 0
            END AS "Payment_Term_Days"
    FROM    "RPT_VIEW"."RPT_PO_INFO" 
    WHERE   "Global_Account" IN ('12145', '12155')
  )
)
SELECT "Org_ID",
       "Vendor_Name",
       "Vendor_Number",
       "PO_Project",
       "PO_Number",
       "PO_Distribution_ID", -- Not sure about PO date, differnt lines under same PO has different Line_create_date
       "Invoice_Date",
       "First_Due_Date",
       "Invoice_ID",
       "Company_Code",
       Adj2020_Estimated_Payment_Date,
       Inv_Line_Amt_USD_Dist,
       "Payment_Date",
       Paid_Amt_Dist_PO_USD,
       "Unpaid_USD_Abs"
       --, First_layer
       --, Second_layer
       --, Third_layer
FROM   t4 
       LEFT JOIN t5
       ON t4."PO_Distribution_ID" = t5."PO_Distribution_Id"
```

You can easily copy-paste the query and remove parts to just run the `t2` or `t5` parts independently of the others and check that they work (add `SELECT * FROM t2` to the end rather than your previous final query). Similarly, you can check whether `t2` + `t4` work. Then you can check whether the entire query works. By using a `WITH` clause then using a divide-and-conquer approach becomes so much simpler.

Then you should see that in the final query `"PO_Project"`  and `"PO_Distribution_ID"` are in both `t4` and `t5` and when you include that column in the `SELECT` clause you need to prefix which inline-view you are selecting the value from. There may be more identifiers that need aliases adding - I stopped looking after I found the first couple but you can check the rest.